# how to share sqlite database in flutter

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, dart

I built my database through SQLITE.
I read the values from the database and created my page.
Then I realized one fact. IOS and ANDROID have different paths in which DATABASE is stored.

It is my database code :

```
initDB() async{
    Directory dbDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(dbDir.path, "social2.db");
    print('init...');
    print(path);
    return await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 1,
      onOpen: (db) {},
      onCreate: (Database db, int version) async{
        await db.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE $tableName(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        email TEXT,
        password TEXT,
        name TEXT,
        intro TEXT,
        age TEXT,
        image0 BLOB,
        image1 BLOB,
        image2 BLOB,
        image3 BLOB,
        image4 BLOB,
        image5 BLOB,
        vote INTEGER,
        location TEXT) ''');
      },
    );
  }
```

How can I use my database normally?

Comment: Those are two different devices right? iOS and Android has different file structure. It shouldn't matter for the Apps.

Comment: @ChennaReddy So what do I do to get you to use the same DB?

Comment: I didn't get your question, what do you mean by same DB? It's a different DB on different device right? It might have different paths on iOS and Android, but that can't be a problem.

Comment: @ChennaReddy Strangely, my app works well because the IOS DB is working properly, but the ANDROID does not work.... :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `path_provider` plugin then it supports both iOS and Android as stated in [its documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider#-readme-tab-)

> A Flutter plugin for finding commonly used locations on the filesystem. Supports iOS and Android.